# Depend on selected value show also other values in this array - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

scenario is like that: User clicks on drop down and select post number and depend on this selection div is generated (append div in showing list) with all values (name of office, number, post office, website, ..) which is in array, but I have only one value from selection (post number).

sample array:

```
var array = [
{
   "id":"1",
   "name":"name 1",
   "address":"address 1",
   "postoffice":"99999",
   "phone":"5060607070",
   "website":"webisteurl1"

},
{
    "id":"2",
    "name":"name 2",
    "address":"address 2",
    "postoffice":"88888",
    "phone":"5060607070",
    "website":"webisteurl2"
 }
]
```

Now I don't know how can select other values in this array depend on selected value (postoffice "99999")

Thanks for directions,

Comment: As per my understanding, you must a empty option in you dropdown.example
<select><option>Select Post Office</option><option value='99999'>name 1</option></select>

Comment: no, first user click on dropdown on postoffice (9999) and then I must find in database (array) in which array is this value and grab all values from this array so I can create div with correct informations: <div><span>postoffice</span>, <span>phone</span>, <span>website</span>, ...</div>

Comment: then, you just show a link, with empty <div>, Once user clicks on postoffice (9999). you act on it. You may update your question with more information.

Comment: Can the user select only the postoffice or also other things like name?

Comment: only postoffice ...I will try whole solution with ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should be what you want:

```js
var postoffice = {
  "99999": {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "name 1",
    "address": "address 1",
    "phone": "5060607070",
    "website": "webisteurl1"

  },
  "88888": {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "name 2",
    "address": "address 2",
    "phone": "5060607070",
    "website": "webisteurl2"
  }
}

var select = document.getElementById('postoffice');
var target = document.getElementById('target');

select.onchange = function() {
  var officeValue = this.value;
  var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  target.innerHTML = '';

  for (key in postoffice[officeValue]) {
    var newSpan = document.createElement("span");
    var spanValue = postoffice[officeValue][key] + ', ';

    newSpan.innerText = spanValue;
    newDiv.appendChild(newSpan);
  }

  target.appendChild(newDiv);
};
```

```html
<div>
  <select id="postoffice">
    <option value="" selected>select postoffice</option>
    <option value="88888">88888</option>
    <option value="99999">99999</option>
  </select>
  <div id="target">
  </div>
</div>
```